# PHP Menu - Loading from Database, can't get structure right

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I'm having a hard time getting this menu to work properly.

`function writeMenu(){
 echo "<div id=\"menu\">" <ul id=\"top-link\">";
          m("top", "n"); echo "</ul></div>";` (sorry, it wouldn't format properly)

```
    function m($parent,$issub){
      $parentQ = "select * from cdi_menu";//gets menu items from menu table
      $parentResult = mysql_query($parentQ); //runs menu item query and obtains result
      while ($link = mysql_fetch_assoc($parentResult)) {//for each line in the result do the folowing:
        if($parent==$link['PARENT']){//if the next link belongs to this menu item
          echo "\n    <li><a href=\"".$link['LINK']."\">".$link['DISPLAY']."</a></li>";
          if($issub=="n" && $link['HASCHILD']=="y"){//if this menu item is a top menu item
            echo "\n  <li id=\"sub-link\"><ul>";
            m($link['ID'], $links, "y");
            echo "\n  </ul></li>";
          }
        }
      }
    }

    echo writeMenu();
```

What I'm trying to do is make it where I can hide the 'sub-link' IDs (I would use classes, but javascript doesn't seem to edit class styles, just IDs). The sub-link items would show when over a parent item.

`top` refers to the top elements, and `ID` refers to the unique id in database.

Thanks, sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: Don't use mysql_*. Look into PDO, and MySQLi. Also, use a JavaScript library like jQuery. You can select classes that way.

Comment: Also, what's the structure of your database table? Without knowing the columns and their values, it's hard to help with this.

Comment: ID, PARENT, LINK, DISPLAY, HASCHILD is the structure. I'll look into those 2.

Comment: So, if it's a parent link, what is the value of the field? The same with haschild?

Comment: The last programmer made the main links under PARENT as `top` and if it is `top` and HASCHILD is `y`, it should show the links tied to it by the ID field. So if Imaging is ID 6, PARENT top, and HASCHILD y, the ID 7, 8, 9 have the value of PARENT 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has only 2 parameters but You call it with 3 inside

```
m($link['ID'], $links, "y");
```

$links is unnecessary.

It would be better if You modify query to look like this

```
$parentQ = "select * from cdi_menu WHERE parent='$parent'";
```

so You don't need first if statement and You will not fetching all rows multiple times for each menu/submenu.

Comment: I took it out and changed the `$parentQ`. What it's doing is putting out the top 3 links, then on mouseover, I have it showing/hiding the sub-links. It currently just shows the set from the 1st top-link

Comment: It means this `if($issub=="n" && $link['HASCHILD']=="y")` statement fails. 1st condition is obviously true so double-check value of haschild in database.